# Flutter/Dart : How to wait for asynchronous task before app starts?

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart, caching, sharedpreferences

I am working on a dart application where I want to fetch the data present in cache (SharedPreferences) and then show it on UI (home screen) of the app.

Problem : Since SharedPreferences is an await call, my home page loads, tries to read the data and app crashes because data fetch has not yet happened from SharedPreferences, and app loads before that.

How can I not start the app until cache read from SharedPreferences is done?
This is required because I have to display data from SharedPreferences on home page of the app.
Various view files of my project call static function : MyService.getValue(key) which crashes as cacheResponseJson has not populated yet. I want to wait for SharedPreferences to complete before my app starts.

```html
Class MyService {
    String _cacheString;
    static Map < String, dynamic > cacheResponseJson;
    MyService() {
        asyncInit();
    }

    Future < void > asyncInit() async {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        _cacheString = sharedPreferences.getString(“ConfigCache”);
        cacheResponseJson = jsonDecode(ecsCacheString);
    }

    static String getValue(String key) {
        return cacheResponseJson[key];
    }
}

void main() {
    MyService s = MyService();
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You can run code in your `main()` method, before the call to `runApp()` that kicks off your application.

For example:

```dart
void main() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();  // makes sure plugins are initialized
    final sharedPreferences = MySharedPreferencesService();  // however you create your service
    final config = await sharedPreferences.get('config');
    runApp(MyApp(config: config));
}
```

Comment: This is what I do.  I don't know if making main async is a good practice, but it hasn't crashed yet. :-)

Comment: A dart program first finds a function called `main()` and executes it, then runs until all asynchronous work is completed. Whether `main()` has the `async` keyword doesn't matter, for example, you could write: `void main() {_main();}` where `_main()` is is `async`, and the behaviour would be the same. In short, its completely fine to make your main method `async`.

Comment: `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` important

Answer (score 0):

Can you try wrapping the function  `asyncInit() in initstate` then in the function then `setstate` the values

```
_cacheString = sharedPreferences.getString(“ConfigCache”);
cacheResponseJson = jsonDecode(ecsCacheString);
```

I hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

avoid using initialization etc outside the `runApp()` function, you can create a singleton

```
class MyService{
  MyService._oneTime();

  static final _instance = MyService._oneTime();

  factory MyService(){
    return _instance;
  }

  Future <bool> asyncInit() async {
    //do stuff
    return true;
  }
}
```

and incorporate that in the UI like this

```
runApp(
  FutureBuilder(
    future: MyService().asyncInit(),
    builder: (_,snap){
      if(snap.hasData){
        //here you can use the MyService singleton and its members
        return MaterialApp();
      }
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    },
  )
);
```

if you take this approach you can do any UI related feedback for the user while the data loads